# Windows - How to output a Cgi file

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I have a cpp project which I can compile and execute as an exe.

However I am learning about distributed systems and I need a cgi file, this file will be put under the cgi-bin folder on my apache server (xampp).

Any idea how can I do this in windows ?

I have problems with getting the particular cgi extensions, also do I need to configure anything in my xampp apache server to run this cgi files. I have noticed the server itself had 3 files when it installed so I thought it was automatically configured.

Comment: Which part; how to configure your webserver to execute cgi programs under a particular path or with a particular extension? Or how to write a program that follows yhe CGI spec? Or how to output HTML to STDOUT?

Comment: @DavidO Hmmm now I will edit my question, isn't xampp already configured to run cgi files.... there were about 3 cgi files there when the program finished installing. I wanted help with the particular extension, but if it needs particular configuring to run the cgi programs plz help me with that also.

Comment: Alright, so it's a question of how the CGI spec works. It's really faitly simple in principle, but beyond the scope of  a SO question/answer. You should first find a tutorial, then ask a specific question rather than a "the whole thing" kind of question. There is just too much to cover, and it's already covered at length online.

Comment: @DavidO buddy no. I already have the written code, I just want a cgi file and I don't want to compile it on linux, I want to know if there is a way in which I can do this in windows. And you were the one talking about specific configurations on the server when I don't think there are any needed.

Comment: @DavidO I do not want to be " spoonfed " , I searched google and I couldn't find anything related to getting a cgi file from a c source code one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically about Windows, but I tested the following on my Apache2 on my Linux (Ubuntu) server.

You can run a CGI by the extension "cgi".  I compiled a "HelloWorld" C++ program and named it "HelloWorldC.cgi" and it executed properly as long as I specified the correct Content-type output.

The C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

The HTML Code:
(test.html)

```
<a href="HelloWorldC.cgi">HelloWorldC.cgi</a>
```

The output when loading the test.html link in a browser:

```
!!!Hello World!!!
```

I believe the problem with Windows might be it's strictness to run program types strictly by the extension.  Linux will run the program according to what it happens to be (by the program's header).  Apache will perform a CGI output on a program run by the configured CGI options.

For Windows you might be able to get your server to execute the program by adding ".exe" to the mime handler types.

i.e. (add .exe to the addhandler directive):

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .exe
```